# about NEMA 6-15 plug/receptacle for 240 V

Tags: wiring, subpanel

The NEMA 6-15 plug/receptacle for 240 V power supply looks like the following:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nema_6-15.svg

The two hots obviously should be connected to the two hot wires in the subpanel. But I am confused with the third one, the U shape hole. Should it be connected to the neutral bar or ground bar in the subpanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### That's a ground hole and goes to the ground bar

The NEMA 6 is a "hot-hot-ground" that supplies 240V *exclusively*.  So, the U-shaped ground-hole on the receptacle is connected to the yoke and in turn, the green ground screw on the receptacle, which needs to be wired to the ground bar on the subpanel.